# How to resolve this error to install SQL Server Express?

Tags: sql-server-express

I am getting this error while installing `SQL Server 2019 Express` on my PC.
Can anyone help me with this? I am really stuck with this the error is

> Cannot find service{0} Parameter name: SQLWRITER

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MDSO.png)

Comment: Uninstall the complete server application, then reinstall it. This time, do a custom installation, select few features including the database engine (not all the features). After a complete installation, you can go back to the installation package and install the remaining ones. That's what I did when I was having challenges installing mine.

Comment: Ensure you're not installing the 64bits edition if your system is 32bits